# Galois Action on Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, schemes

Let $X$ be a $K$-scheme and $L \vert K$ be a Galois extension with Galois group $G= Gal(L,K)$.

Let consider the base change $X_L := X \otimes_K L:= X \times_{Spec(K)} Spec(L)$. Since $X_L$ is a $L$-scheme $G$ can act on it.

My problems are following: I see some ways $G$ acting on $X_L$ and on it's structure sheaf but I'm not sure if they all coinside/corelate to each other and why?

1. Let $g \in G$ then it induce an automorphism $g: Spec(L) \to Spec(L)$ and one can define the action of $g$ on $X_L$ via commutative diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_L @>{\bar{g}}  >> X_L \\
@VVprV  @VVprV  \\
Spec(L) @>{g}>> Spec(L);
\end{CD}
$$

or sugestively $\bar{g}: id_X \times g$

2. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module.
   I heard that $G$ can induce canonically an "$\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$-linear-action" on tnduced sheaf $\mathscr{F}\otimes \mathcal{O}_L$ acting on local sections $\mathcal{F}(U)$ for open $U$.

How concretely this action is described? Comes it from the same action as in case 1.?

In the sense of local action $(\mathcal{F}(U) \otimes_K L) ^g =  \mathcal{F}(U) \otimes_K L^g$ ? So only on second summand? Or are these two actions different?

Espesially I don't see how could $G$ act on local sections of an arbitrary $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module $\mathcal{F}$.

Futhermore this concept allows to define the so called sub-$\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$-module $\mathcal{F}^G \subset \mathcal{F}$ of invariants. But with respect to which action of $G$?

So the main point of my question is if 1. and 2. "generate" the same action and how this action extends to $\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$-modules.

Is this exactly  THE canonical Galois action on a scheme which in the literature often mentioned but nowhere explicitely described?

Comment: Well 1 and 2 act on different things. 1 acts on the scheme $X_L$ by morphisms of schemes, and 2 acts on $\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$-modules by morphisms of the same. They certainly aren't the same action thus you may want to ask, instead of whether or not they are the same action, whether each gives rise to the other or something like that.

Comment: @jgon:Ah sorry, I guess I forgot to explain some detail. If the action from 1. acts on $X_L$ then obviously induce an action on $\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$ since the structure sheaf belongs to the data on $X_L$. The question is if the action from 1. then extends from the action on $\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$ to arbitrary $\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$-module and if it coinside with 2.

The thing is that a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ induce locally a $\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$-module structure via $\mathcal{F}(U) \otimes_K L$ and here 1. can induce naively action.

Comment: The thing is that a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ induce locally a $\mathcal{O}_{X_L}$-module structure via $\mathcal{F}(U) \otimes_K L$ and here 1. can induce naively action.

Comment: sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear either. My issue with that idea is that in 1 it doesn't preserve open sets (as in $U$ and $gU$ aren't always the same set) (at least I don't think it does) it certainly doesn't preserve points. Also it acts by ring morphisms not module morphisms, so I'm not sure how you'd get the action in 2 to have those properties, but if it is possible, it would still not be an action I'd call the same as in 1.

Comment: Also your comments now leave me confused as to whether $\mathcal{F}$ should be a module on $X$ or $X_L$

Comment: @jgon: Yes, I think I see the problem which prevents to extend the action in 1. to the structure sheaf or other sheaves over $X$. Hmmm seems that 1. und 2. are indeed two diferent things.

Concerning your 4. post I think that indeed that I meant by $\mathcal{F}$ modules on $X$. Since then - again quite naively - I could locally $G$ let act on $\mathcal{F}(U) \otimes_K L$ by acting on $L$. So $\mathcal{F}$ just induce a module over $X_L$ but isn't one.

Comment: @jgon: So it seems that there is no connecting between them two? The problem is that literature talks often about the "canonic action by $G$". But what is here the canonic action?

Comment: if $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of modules on $X$, then there is a canonical action of $G$ on it, and indeed, it is precisely what you've indicated. Both actions of $G$ are canonical, $G$ just acts canonically on different objects in each action. Since an action on one object doesn't induce an action on the other, there's no confusion over which action is meant.

Comment: @jgon: So these both are the only two so called "canonical" Galois actions occuring in algebraic geometry? (in the sense that they are used without explicitely description what the action does)

Comment: I seriously doubt it. The word canonical is used all over the place, and actions of the Galois group are precisely the kind of thing that crops up nicely in ways that we would call canonical, though I don't have an example of another "canonical Galois action" off the top of my head.